# AWS CloudWatch Dashboard for Large Screen Display with Alerting

Tags: monitoring, amazon-web-services, alerting, amazon-cloudwatch

Does anyone know of a good solution that provides a monitoring and alerting Dashboard for Amazon Web Servics (AWS) CloudWatch service which can used on large screen displays?

The system should use the CloudWatch API, not need an agent to be installed on the instances.

Answer (score 1):

There's [this CloudWatch-Librato connector](https://github.com/mapbox/cloudwatch-librato#readme) (implemented in Node.js). It's brand new and features are still being added, so if you're in for an early adopter experience you may want to give it a try; otherwise you could keep an eye on it and try a little later. Full disclosure: I work at Librato.

Comment: Your bit.ly link comes right back here...

Comment: Oops... fixed it